# Как загрузить скриншот страницы на сервер

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, веб-программирование

Как загрузить скриншот страницы на сервер?
Доброе время суток!

Мне нужно сделать скрин части страницы и загрузить его на сервер без перезагрузки страницы.

Я нашел библиотеку html2canvas.js. Оно решат мой вопрос, делая base64 строку и передавая ее в php:

```
JS:
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnCapture').on("click", function () {
          captureAndUpload();
        });
        function captureAndUpload() {
          $('body').html2canvas({
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
              var i = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
              $.ajax({
                url: "http://artultra/save.php?img=" + i ,
                type:"post",
                async: false,
                proccessData: false,
                success: function(response){
                  alert('ok')
                },
                error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                  alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
              });

            }
          });
        }
      });

PHP:
        $data = $_REQUEST['img'];
        list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
        list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
        $data = base64_decode($data);
        file_put_contents('image.png', $data);
```

При отправке картинки формируется очень длинный url (более 2000 символов). И выливает про это ошибка 414 (Request-URI Too Large).

Как можно можно решить этот вопрос не откручивая гайки apache? Есть какая альтернатива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем вы отправляете `POST` запрос, а данные передаёте как `GET` параметры?

Что бы отправить данные как `POST` надо:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://artultra/save.php",
    type:"post",
    data: {
        img : i
    },
    success: function() {},
    error: function() {}
});
```

Так же они будут доступны из `$_POST`/`$_REQUEST`  массива в вашем варианте только `$_GET`/`$_REQUEST`